# How do I get the currently focused element when using VoiceOver on iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, accessibility, voiceover

I have a table with cells that the user may swipe to mark them "completed". I am trying to make this accessible using VoiceOver by implementing the accessbilityScroll method.

This works fine, but I can't figure out what cell has focus when the user scrolls.

I only find information on how to *change* focus.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Hehe, Ok. I just figured it out.

There is a protocol for this. Its called [UIAccessibilityFocus](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIAccessibilityFocus_Protocol/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Method: `accessibilityElementDidBecomeFocused:`

Well, I will leave this question here to any one else that is out there struggling with this.

Comment: I also created a category on UIView, and override the function in there. This provides a nice global callback which gets hit every time the state changes. See my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/40914451/1532838

Comment: what is the equivalent of this API in macOS/OSX. I need to know which element is currently focused by Accessibility. Based on the focused element i want to write some logic.

Comment: @AnanthKamath I havent worked with iOS in 10 years and I have never worked with macOS so my your guess is as good as mine 

Answer (score 4):

Your program can also tell where VoiceOver’s “focus” (the object that it’s dealing with) is, and when “focus” enters or leaves any given object.

[For Focus Information click here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIAccessibilityFocus_Protocol/Introduction/Introduction.html)

```
– accessibilityElementDidBecomeFocused

– accessibilityElementDidLoseFocus

– accessibilityElementIsFocused
```

Comment: Yes, it is part of the protocol UIAccessibilityFocus, which I mentioned in my own answer. Isnt your answer the same as mine ?

Answer (score 2):

As of iOS9, you can use

```
UIAccessibilityFocusedElement(UIAccessibilityNotificationVoiceOverIdentifier)
```

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/1615119-uiaccessibilityfocusedelement