# Accessibility voiceover single swipe gestures in Swift IOS

Tags: ios, accessibility, swipe, gesture, voiceover

I am working on the IOS application, related to voice over, my Question is : When accessibility voice over was enabled how can i get the swipe gestures left, right, top and down, what re the function for detecting these in swift?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you need to let VoiceOver know that about your view (or another element). So if you are in a view controller, this should work: `self.view.isAccessibilityElement = true`

Second, you need to let VoiceOver know that your view will handle user interactions on its own: `self.view.accessibilityTraits = UIAccessibilityTraitAllowsDirectInteraction`. After that your view should start getting gestures notifications.

Here's another relevant answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20712889/2219578

Answer (score 0):

It isn't possible to catch the left, right, top and bottom VoiceOver gestures : I've seen neither a protocol nor a kind of notification for this.

However, you can detect a [scrolling action](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1615161-accessibilityscroll) and be aware of the [element focus](http://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/mobile_EN/dev-ios.html#focus-an-element) provided by VoiceOver.