# Is there a way to detect VoiceOver focus change / user interaction at the `UIApplication` or `UIWindow` level?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, accessibility, voiceover

One of the features of the app I'm working on is an "idle timeout" - basically if the user doesn't interact with the app for more than five minutes, their session ends for privacy / security reasons.

This is currently implemented by overriding `sendEvent(_ event: UIEvent)` in the app delegate and resetting a timer.

However, what I've noticed is that `sendEvent(_ event: UIEvent)` isn't called at all when a user is interacting with the app using VoiceOver.

It **is** called when the user double-taps to activate a control, but it **isn't** called for focus changes, interacting with `.adjustable` controls, and so on.

This means that if a user is swiping through a long list of rows in a table view, for example, `sendEvent(_ event: UIEvent)` isn't called and a user may be timed-out of the app, even though they were interacting with it.

Is there a way to detect VoiceOver focus changes or interactions at the `UIApplication` or `UIWindow` level, or a notification that can be subscribed to for a clean solution?

The closest solution I've found suggests using the `UIAccessibilityFocus` protocol on individual views, but this feels like it could be quite messy and involve a lot of subclassing (https://stackoverflow.com/a/20712889).

Any different suggestions for an idle timeout that works for VoiceOver and non-VoiceOver users would also be much appreciated - there could well be something I've missed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured out the solution here and I'm now kicking myself.

`UIAccessibility.elementFocusedNotification` is the key (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiaccessibility/1620210-elementfocusednotification).

So a solution could look something like:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                       selector: #selector(self.accessibilityElementFocussed(notification:)),
                                       name: UIAccessibility.elementFocusedNotification,
                                       object: nil)

@objc private func accessibilityElementFocussed(notification: NSNotification) {
    // Reset your idle timer here.
}
```

Hopefully this helps someone out - I've seen a lot of solutions for idle timers online that don't take into account VoiceOver users.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the solution based on listening to UIAccessibility.elementFocusedNotification only solves part of the problem.

The notification is not generated when you click again on an already focused item (which is certainly logical). Besides, activation of elements without accessoryLabel also does not result in notification generation (when VoiceOver is enabled).

Therefore, developing an idle timer that takes VoiceOver into account is not yet fully possible.