# Swift how to know currently focused object by accessibility VoiceOver engine

Tags: swift, notifications, accessibility, nsnotificationcenter

I need to know which element is currently become focused by accessibility focus engine. In a simple case, let' say I have come cell with a couple of label. I need to know (i.e. print on console, or doing other stuff) which object is currently focused. Them same if I had a view with a lot of subviews, of different type. I think I should use elementFocusedNotification, and as told in docs, use the key `UIAccessibilityElementFocusedKeyElement`. I think I should pass the object in the method, but how?.

among others, I looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36910965/how-to-pass-data-using-notificationcenter-in-swift-3-0-and-nsnotificationcenter), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20498678/how-do-i-get-the-currently-focused-element-when-using-voiceover-on-ios) and [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/1615119-uiaccessibilityfocusedelement) for info, but cannot find solutions to know which element is currently focused.

in my cellForRowAt indexPath:

in the cell:

```
override func accessibilityElementDidBecomeFocused() {
        NotificationCenter.default.post(
            name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: UIAccessibility.elementFocusedNotification.rawValue),
            object: self.subviews.first(where: {$0.isFocused}),
            userInfo: ["UIAccessibilityElementFocusedKeyElement": "hello there"]
        )
    }
```

in the controller's viewDidLoad:

```
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
        self,
        selector: #selector(self.doSomething(_:)),
        name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: UIAccessibility.elementFocusedNotification.rawValue),
        object: nil
    )
```

in the same controller

```
@objc func catchNotification(_ notification: Notification) {
    //print("subscribed, notification: \(notification)")

    if let myNotification1 = notification.userInfo?["UIAccessibilityElementFocusedKeyElement"] {
        print("+++", myNotification1)
    }

   }
```

Comment: What's in your 'in my cellForRowAt indexPath:' ? You forgot to write that down

Comment: I _think_ you can observe the changes of focused items. Try observing `UIAccessibilityVoiceOverStatusDidChangeNotification` and then see what's inside its `userInfo`

Answer (score 1):

First of all cell will never be focused.

1. VoiceOver focus single accessibility element and do not inform it's superviews.

So if you want to use `accessibilityElementDidBecomeFocused()` you will have to   override `UILabel`

2. `UIAccessibility.elementFocusedNotification` is send by system, you probably should never post it by yourself
3. Going back to your problem.
   I suppose that you have following situation:

```
ViewController
  TableView
    Cell 1
      Label 1_1
      Label 1_2
      Label 1_3
      View 1_1
    Cell 2
      Label 2_1
      Label 2_2
      Label 2_3
      View 2_1
    Cell 3
      ...
```

and whenever VO focus `Label_i_*` or `View_i_*` you want to inform yours controller that i-th element was focused.

My approach will be as follow:

- every accessibility element should know which element is displaying
- view controller catches every notification, checks if it was send by TableView's subview and if so then it get element from it

The code will be as follow:

```
class MyViewController ... {
    private var VOFocusChanged: NSObjectProtocol?

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        VOFocusChanged = NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
            forName: UIAccessibility.elementFocusedNotification,
            object: nil,
            queue: OperationQueue.main
        ) {
            [weak self] (notification: Notification) in
            self?.handleVONotification(notification)
        }
    }
    
    override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidDisappear(animated)
        
        // there is no reason to observe changes 
        // if we know that view is no longer visible
        if let VOFocusChanged: NSObjectProtocol = VOFocusChanged {
            NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(VOFocusChanged)
        }
    }
   
    private func handleVONotification(_ notification: Notification) {
        if let focusedView: UIView = notification.userInfo?[
                UIAccessibility.focusedElementUserInfoKey
            ] as? UIView {

            if focusedView.isGrandson(of: view) {
                if let fView: ViewWithElement = focusedView as? ViewWithElement {
                    elementsWasFocused(fView.element)
                }
            }
        }

    }
    
    private func elementsWasFocused(_ element: T) {
        // add your logic here
    }
 
}

extension UIView {
    func isGrandson(of view: UIView) -> Bool {
        if superview === view {
            return true
        }
        return superview?.isGrandson(of: view) ?? false
    }
}


protocol ViewWithElement {
    var element: T { get }
}

// Use this instead of label inside UITableViewCell 
class MyLabel: UILabel, ViewWithElement {

    func display(element: T) {
        _element = element
        text = ...
        accessibilityLabel = ...
    }
    // MARK: ViewWithElement
    private var _element: T!
    
    var element: T { return _element }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a direct answer to your question, nor I'm certain if it all works as I say. Because Apple hides a lot of details of how the accessibility engine works, but still may help solve your problem from a completely different angle and the sense that you don't need to know what's the current focus.

Take a look at a few of Apple's own apps. e.g. the Settings App. Only the entire cell is accessible. The labels are not.

The solution is to either:

- based on your labels `override` the accessibilityLabel of the cell and then set `isAccessibilityElement` to `false` for your labels. For more on that see [Making Your iOS App Accessible](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/iPhoneAccessibility/Making_Application_Accessible/Making_Application_Accessible.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008785-CH102-SW4). Scroll down to 'Enhance the Accessibility of Table Views'
- just manually set the `accessibilityLabel` when necessary and then set `isAccessibilityElement` to `false` for your labels. Apparently this solution would require you to reset it if the label gets updated.
- if you set a view or text for your `accessoryView` then I *believe* UITableViewCell will take its value into consideration as well. For more on that see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24498614/combine-uiswitch-and-uitableviewcell-for-voiceover-interaction)

Note: A tableviewcell's accessibilityLabel will default to its labels's text.